# Python's UnboundLocalError and inline variables' assignment

Tags: python, closures, variable-assignment

Here's a method which returns a method which each time called returns the next fibonacci number (0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ...).

```
def make_fib():
    j, k = 0, 1
    def fib():
        nonlocal j, k
        result = j
        j, k = k, j+k
        return result
return fib
```

While the above works fine, if I break the inline assignment of j and k to different assignments, it throws a UnboundLocalError: local variable 'j' referenced before assignment:

```
  def make_fib():
      j, k = 0, 1
      def fib():
          nonlocal j, k
          result = j
          j = k
          k = j+k
          return result
      return fib
```

Why is that?

Comment: The two functions are different, but I don't see the error you reference.  Are you sure this is the code you actually ran?  Keep in mind that `j = k` followed by `k = j+k` won't do what you want, since the second assignment will use the new value of `j`, which is just `k`.  So it will produce `0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16,` etc.

Comment: If you want to split up the assignment, you need to do: `t = j; j = k, k = t + k`

Comment: Thanks @TomKarzes, you're right about both. The error reported comes from not declaring j as a `nonlocal` variable.